# I Don't Understand This Array Syntax

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

I don't understand this array accessing syntax:

```
$target[$segs[count($segs)]]
```

Is it really possible to use variables as multidimensional array keys?

Comment: You've asked largely the same question four times in as many minutes. Please stop opening new questions and simply update an existing one if appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [at what scene do we use this php array ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732528/at-what-scene-do-we-use-this-php-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might result in an error, if `$segs` is a numerical array with continuous indices only.
 Meaning, it would fail for:

```
array("foo","bar");
```

but work for

```
array("foo", 2=>"bar");
```

Assuming now, that we deal with the first case, then this would work:

```
$target[$segs[count($segs) - 1]]
```

First, `count($segs) - 1` will be evaluated and return a number. In this case the *last index* of `$segs` (provided it is a numerical array).

`$segs[count($segs) - 1]` will therefore return the *last element* in `$segs`. And whatever that value is, will be used as index for `$target[...]`.

---

**To sum up:** It is nested array indexing and evaluated inside out.

[See it in action.](http://codepad.org/9hoWq1RD)

Whether or not such a method is necessary depends on the problem you are trying to solve. If you don't know where you would use such nested, variable array indexing then you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is fine, provided `$segs` is an array. It's worth noting, though, that if you're using a numerically indexed array for `$segs`, calling `count($segs)` is a non-existent key because indexing starts at zero.